# VBA Excel - Generate New Workbook with macros from Old Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a workbook which contains a bunch of data on 2 of the sheets, which i use to construct a chart. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

So, In CRC I have a bunch of macros which pull through data from the Generator and MPNT and Construct the Chart in the CRC when a button on the MPNT is pressed.

**MY ISSUE**

For some reason, when I copy the CRC sheet out into a new worksheet using the function below, and then I use one of the buttons on the worksheet to hide/unhide data columns on the chart, it opens up the original file and uses the macros in that to run these buttons?

```
    '''Extract Worksheet Button Function

Dim OriginalWB As Workbook, NewCRCWB As Workbook

Set OriginalWB = ThisWorkbook
Set NewCRCWB = Workbooks.Add

OriginalWB.Sheets("Generator").Copy Before:=NewCRCWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
OriginalWB.Sheets("Module Part Number Tracker").Copy Before:=NewCRCWB.Sheets("Generator")
OriginalWB.Sheets("CRC").Copy Before:=NewCRCWB.Sheets("Module Part Number Tracker")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
NewCRCWB.Worksheets("Generator").Visible = False
NewCRCWB.Worksheets("Module Part Number Tracker").Visible = False
NewCRCWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete

NewCRCWB.Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

**MY AIM**

To get around this I need to develop a function which will create a new workbook, and do all of the generation straight into that workbook and transfer the macros into there, however I'm not sure how to do this hence

**MY QUESTION**

How do I:

1. Open a New Workbook
2. Run the macros from CRC in current
   workbook onto a CRC sheet on the newly opened workbook
3. In the process ensure that all the macros are copied through to the CRC
   sheet in the New Workbook

Thanks!!

Comment: Why don't you save the current workbook as a new workbook, run the chart etc, and then delete the sheets you don't want. Does this get you to the same end point ?

Comment: I agree with @RobinMackenzie. Saving the workbook as a new workbook is a far less complex system than using the VBA VBE api. The VBE api is pretty terrible... Failing this, your next best bet would be transferring the VB project by unzipping the xlsm and transfering the vba files. You can easily do this from the command line even.